# Контрольная сумма настроек BIOS

Tags: c++, c, bios

Цель: Проверки изменения настроек BIOS-а при старте системы (сравнение контрольных сумм).

Какие конкретно настройки изменились не важно, интересен сам факт изменения.

Вопрос: куда копать? Где теоретический это может хранится?

PS: Посмотрел сумму в CMOS (2EH-2FH), остается постоянной, изменения настроек на нее не влияет.

Comment: А почему просто не запомнить все настройки, перечитать и сравнить?